# Spring cloud api gateway not sending POST request correctly

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlets, microservices, spring-cloud-gateway

I have two applications

- a. monolith (developed with java servlet)
- b. Spring boot microservice (in development)

I am trying to develop spring cloud api gateway which will sit infront of this two apps and will serve the traffic based on what request it receives. Mostly both apps support POST method and routing in api gateway works fine for b.spring boot microservice but when same request and url I tried on monolith its been observed that spring cloud api gateway sending GET request (which is not allowed ) and getting failed with 404 error. Is there any way to identify what exact request api gateway tried ? OR does api gateway try first GET and then POST ?

I am able to confirm that I am receiving GET request on the POST request that I tried on api gateway by checking the access logs

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [14/Jul/2022:12:34:31 -0700] "**GET** /myservice/revers HTTP/1.1" 404 1685 "PostmanRuntime/7.29.0" "0/455"
```

logs from api gateway after enabling the TRACE

```
2022-07-15 01:04:30.426  INFO 16016 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] c.t.tes.gwapi.config.LoggingFilter   : Incoming request http://localhost:8080/servlet ,is routed uri:http://10.2.1.55:3068/myservice/revers with id: my-route-id
2022-07-15 01:04:31.665 DEBUG 16016 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [d95e4f2a-1, L:/10.01.57.01:59773 - R:/10.2.1.55:3068] Handler is being applied: {uri=http://10.2.1.55:3068/myservice/revers , method=POST}
2022-07-15 01:04:31.974 DEBUG 16016 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] r.n.http.client.HttpClientOperations     : [d95e4f2a-1, L:/10.01.57.01:59773 - R:/10.2.1.55:3068] Received response (auto-read:false) : [Date=Thu, 14 Jul 2022 19:34:31 GMT, Server=Apache, Last-Modified=Wed, 06 Jul 2022 09:15:29 GMT, Accept-Ranges=bytes, Content-Type=text/html, content-length=1685]
2022-07-15 01:04:31.983 DEBUG 16016 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] r.n.http.client.HttpClientOperations     : [d95e4f2a-1, L:/10.01.57.01:59773 - R:/10.2.1.55:3068] Received last HTTP packet
2022-07-15 01:04:31.987  INFO 16016 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] c.t.t.gwapi.config.SpringCloudConfig     : Response body <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
sample html
```

Here is sample api config

```
@Bean
    public RouteLocator myRouteSavingRequestBody(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route("my-route-id",
                        p -> p
                                .path("/servlet/**") //your own path filter
                                .filters(f -> f
                                        .modifyResponseBody(String.class, String.class,
                                                (webExchange, originalBody) -> {
                                                    if (originalBody != null) {
                                                        //log.info("Response body {}", originalBody);
                                                        return Mono.just(originalBody);
                                                    } else {
                                                        return Mono.empty();
                                                    }
                                                })
                                        .modifyRequestBody(String.class, String.class,
                                                (webExchange, originalBody) -> {
                                                    if (originalBody != null) {
                                                       // log.info("Request body {}", originalBody);
                                                        return Mono.just(originalBody);
                                                    } else {
                                                        return Mono.empty();
                                                    }
                                                })
                                        .setPath("/myservice/revers")

                                )
                               .uri("http://10.2.1.55:3068")
                )
                .build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nginx redirect could result in the reuqest method change. I used RouteLocator as a gateway to redirect a POST request to a HTTPS url, but I wrote a wrong uri with a HTTP url, so the Nginx redirect to HTTPS and send a GET request instead of POST request.